# How to request different session IDs from Java-based web-server using python?

Tags: python, jsp, session, cookies, session-cookies

As far as you know, In some web sites, when I send a home-page request to the web server, It assign a session ID to me. Using this session ID and cookies, it prevent multiple sign in (Login with different accounts in a single browser simultaneous). i.e, if I don't signed out, when I send another request to the web server on another tab of my browser, it returns me the same session ID.

Now, I want to receive different session IDs per request. How can I do it?

Comment: If you don't store cookies, the webserver almost definitely will assign you a new session.  There are ways a webserver can attempt to identify you (get/post data, [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), your IP address, etc) -- but most don't care enough.  The problem, however, is depending on what you want to automate, maintaining a session with the server may be necessary.

Comment: @jedwards I want to sign in with 200 different users simultaneously and do some transactions with each user. (for a stress test)

Comment: You might consider the packages [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: @jedwards Thank you. Are you sure they will do my goal?

Comment: Am I sure, no.  But I suspect they will.  It may be a bit easier with mechanize, but mechanize will require more resources.  But I suspect you'll be able to "sign in with 200 different users simultaneously and do some transactions" with either package.